# What is $\text{Hom}_{R\text{-Alg}}(R^{\overline{R}(B)},C)\rightarrow \overline{C}(B)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, synthetic-differential-geometry

I'm reading this [Synthetic Differential Geometry](http://home.math.au.dk/kock/sdg99.pdf) and don't understand (A.1) on page 213.

$\text{Hom}_{R\text{-Alg}}(R^{\overline{R}(B)},C)\xrightarrow{\nu _{B,C}}
\overline{C}(B)$ (A.1)

Would you give me a comprehensible explanation of this $\nu_{B,C}$?

I might understand.

Let $S$ be the functor $\text{Hom}_{R\text{-Alg}}(R^{\overline{R}(-)},C):\text{FP}\mathbb{T}^{op} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$. I want to define $S\xrightarrow{\nu_{C}}\overline{C}$, however, it is suffice to define $S\circ F\rightarrow C$.

Comment: The definition is on the following page. What do you not understand?

Comment: I don't understand the sentence "To describe $\nu_{B,C}$ for all $B\in \text{FP}\mathbb{T}$, it suffices, by Theorem A.1, to describe $\nu_{F(n),C}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{T}$, ...". How is the theorem A.1. used here?

Comment: It is literally the second part of the statement of A.1.

Comment: Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.